# How to ignore an inner nested object when using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Hello I have the classes:

Class User

```
public class User
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }        
    public Profile Profile { get; set; } //EF one to one
}
```

Class Profile

```
    public class Profile 
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } //This is because EF Mappings
}
```

Class User DTO

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }        
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

I did the configurations to Map User to UserDTO

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
```

I need  to have the **Profile.User** because of the *Entity Framework One to One Relationship* but I don't want the Profile.User to be shown in the Mapping.

How can I ignore the Profile.User?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `UserProfileDTO` class that omits `User`

```
public class UserProfileDTO
{
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AddressDTO> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public UserProfileDTO Profile { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Profile, UserProfileDTO>();
```