# Automapper ignore child property in a collection object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, automapper

I have Article and Category models which are related:

```
public class Article
{
    ...

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

 public class Category
 {
     ...

     public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
 }
```

These are their ModelViews:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    ...

    public CategoryViewModel Category { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryViewModel
{
    ...

    public ICollection<ArticleViewModel> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

And this the Automapper:

```
CreateMap<Article, ArticleViewModel>()
.ReverseMap();
```

The code runs in to this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'ArticleViewModel'. Path 'category.articles'.
```

How can i ignore `Category.Articles` collection in the `AutoMapper` when getting the article?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore an inner nested object when using AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882969/how-to-ignore-an-inner-nested-object-when-using-automapper)

Comment: Also relevant is [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/820).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject</*your type*/>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(/*your source*/, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }), deserializeSettings);
```

Comment: I solved it by creating another ViewModel without a collection of ArticleViewModel [How to ignore an inner nested object when using AutoMapper
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882969/how-to-ignore-an-inner-nested-object-when-using-automapper)